# Como declarar e usar a regra @viewport?

Tags: css, html5, mobile, layout-responsivo

Estive lendo que a meta viewport possui melhor implementação pela rule viewport CSS, todavia, ainda está confuso para mim...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*O viewport é a área onde seu website aparece. É a área branca da janela quando você abre o browser. O viewport sempre vai ter o tamanho da janela. Mas a forma como os elementos são renderizados vai depender bastante do dispositivo.*

*Fonte:* https://tableless.com.br/manipulando-metatag-viewport/

**A Meta Tag Viewport**

Use a meta tag viewport, introduzida pela Apple, e então adotada e desenvolvida por mais pessoas.

Ela se parece com isso:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="">
```

Dentro do *content=""* você pode entrar com uma série de valores separados por vírgula, mas vamos focar nos fundamentos agora.

Por exemplo, se o seu layout móvel é definido em 320px, você pode especificar o viewport dessa forma:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320">
```

Para layouts flexíveis é mais prático basear a largura do seu viewport no dispositivo em questão, para igualar a largura do layout à largura do dispositivo você deve digitar:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Para se certificar que o seu layout será mostrado como você planejou, você pode definir o nível de zoom inicial. Isso, por exemplo:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
```

... irá garantir que, após a abertura, o layout será exibido corretamente em escala 1:1. Nenhum zoom será aplicado. Você pode ir mais longe e evitar qualquer zoom pelo usuário:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="maximum-scale=1">
```

> **Nota:** Antes de aplicar o parâmetro de maximum-scale, considere se você realmente deve estar impedindo que os usuários deem o zoom. Eles são capazes de ler tudo da melhor forma possível?

Outra opção é configurar o ViewPort direto pelo CSS, inclusive essa é a recomendação da Microsoft para o Internet Explorer (ie10 e superior)

```
@viewport{
    zoom: 1.0;
    width: device-width;
}
```

***SEM Viewport***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***COM Viewport***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Aqui tem dois excelentes artigos em português que serviram de referencia e vão te ajudar muito!***

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/pt/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972

Comment: Ótima explicação.

Comment: @Leandro valeu jovem! Tmj!

Comment: Muito obrigada!

Comment: @MayaFiuza legal que deu certo!! Se a sua dúvida já foi respondida considere marcar uma resposta como aceita, nesse ícone ✔ a lado da resposta que vc usou, assim a pergunta não fica pendente no site como Pergunta sem Reposta Aceita. Boa sorte com o projeto

Comment: Opa! Grata por lembrar, sou nova por aqui...

Comment: Sem problemas @MayaFiuza seja bem vinda e usa a plataforma para o Bem :)