# Qual seria o modo correto e mais completo para se iniciar um documento html?

Tags: html

Fui iniciar um documento HTML no Sublime Text 3 e nele é possível digitar apenas html:5 e apertar <kbd>tab</kbd> que o corpo inicial de um documento HTML aparece.

Fiz o mesmo com o VS Code e nele já aparecem tags `<meta>` a mais.

Dito isto, qual seria a forma correta e mais completa de se iniciar um documento HTML?

Comment: Leitura recomendada para vc https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/209593/qual-%C3%A9-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-meta-tag-x-ua-compatible-dentro-do-html e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/309370/como-declarar-e-usar-a-regra-viewport/

Comment: Só depende da finalidade. Se houvesse somente uma maneira "correta", as configurações padrão dos navegadores já seriam suficientes.

Answer (score 1):

O *boilerplate* mais básico sempre vai conter um documento padrão usando HTML5 e que tenha algumas *tags* `meta`, o `title` e o `body`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Título do Documento</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Conteúdo HTML do <body> da página. -->
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Mas o modelo inicial realmente varia muito da sua necessidade e das ferramentas que você vai vir a utilizar. Se você for usar Bootstrap na sua aplicação, por exemplo, eles já oferecem um [*template* pronto aqui](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template).

Você também pode usar geradores de templates como:

- [HTMLShell](http://htmlshell.com/);
- [Initializr](http://www.initializr.com/).