# Menu responsivo dropdown não funciona corretamente em dispositivos mobile, como resolver?

Tags: menu, dropdown, layout-responsivo

Olá,

Estou construindo uma página web responsiva com um menu dropdown. No navegador do desktop ela funciona blza, mas no celular não funciona, a página apenas diminui de tamanho sem fazer o dropdown. Utilizo o @media, limitando a largura máxima de 768px, conforme os códigos abaixo:

```css
html, body, header{
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    
}
.topo-logo{
    width: 100%;
    
}
article, main footer, header, nav, section{display: block;}
#tudo{
    width: 100%;
 
    margin-left: 0;
    
}
body{
    
    font-family: "Tahoma" , sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
   

}

/*== Logomarca ==*/

.topo-logo{
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    
}

/*== Menu ==*/

.caixa{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    height: 45px;
    z-index:2 ;
    width: 100%;
    
}
#bt_menu{
    display: none;
    
      
}

label{
    display: block ;
    
}
.container{
    
    margin-top:0%;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu {
    margin-left: 30%;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    
        
    
 }

/*Estilizando as listas */

 .menu ul {
     position: relative;
     list-style: none;
     transition: all .4s;
     justify-content: center;
     padding: 0;
     margin-top: auto;
     align-content: center;
     z-index: 2;
     
 }

.menu li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    display: flex;   
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    
    }
.menu ul li {
    float: left;
    border-top-color: white;
    

 }


.menu a {

 padding: 15px;

 display: block;

 text-decoration: none;

 text-align: justify-all;

 background-color: black;

 color: white;

 }


.menu a:hover {

 background-color: forestgreen;

 color: white;

 }


/*Criando o label */

 label[for=”bt_menu”]{

 padding: 20px;

 background-color: black;

 color: black;

 font-family: sans-serif;

 text-align: left;

 font-size: 30px;

 cursor: pointer;

 height: 100px;
     

 }



label[for=”bt_menu”]{

 display: none;
    background-color: white;

 }
@media (max-width: 768px){ 

    label[for=”bt_menu”] {
        display: block; 
        height: 50px;
        
       
        
 }
 
.caixa{
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative; 
    }

#fale_conosco{
    width: 40%;
    margin top: 0;  
    }


#formulario {
   
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#formulario form{
    
    border: none;
    
    }
#formulario input{
    padding: 10px;
    max-height: 40px;
    }
#mensagem{
        width: 100%;
    }

#bt_menu:checked ~ .menu{

 margin-left: 0;
    

 }

label{ 
    display:block;
    margin-left: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30px;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 1px 0px 0px 4px;
    border-right: 1px solid white;    
        
    }

.menu{
    position: absolute;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: -30%;
    transition: all .4s;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 2;

 }

 
.menu ul li {  /*lista*/
    
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 2;

 }


}

#quem_somos{
   
    font-size: 14;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5%;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Quem Somos</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Site do curso de desenvolvimento Web" /> 
        <meta keywords="site, css, javascript, html"/> <!-- Palavras chave -->
        <meta name="author" content="Higor Lemos"/> <!-- Autor do site -->
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css" />  <!-- liga o html ao css -->
        
    </head>
    
                
                
     <body>
         <div id="tudo">
        <!-- Área de Navegação -->

        <nav class="topo-logo"> <a href="index.html"> 
                <img src="img/logo.png"/ alt="Minha Marca">
            </a>
         </nav>
         
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Menu -->        
       
         <input type="checkbox" id="bt_menu" class="bt_menu"/>
         
        <div class = "caixa"><label for="bt_menu">&#9776;</label></div> 
         

         <nav class="menu">
             <ul>
                 <li> <a href="index.html"> <b> INÍCIO </b> </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="quem_somos.html"> <b> QUEM SOMOS </b> </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="servicos.html"> <b> SERVIÇOS </b> </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="contato.html"> <b> CONTATO </b> </a></li>
                    <li> <a href="fale_conosco.html"> <b> FALE CONOSCO </b> </a></li>
             </ul>
         </nav>
         </div>
        <section id="quem_somos">
            
            <h1> Quem Somos </h1>
            <div>
            <p> A Cactus é uma empresa criada em fevereiro de 2018, em Vitória da Conquista-BA. Atua no ramo de serviços gráficos e venda de produtos.   </p>
            </div>
            <div>
            <h3>Missão</h3>
            <p>Tem como missão "Imprimir sonhos".</p>
            </div>
            <div>
            <h3>Visão</h3>
            <p>Nossa visão é nos tornarmos uma empresa destaque baiano no segmento em que atuamos.</p> 
            </div>

         </section>    
         
        <footer> Desenvolvido por Higor Lemos. </footer>
    </div>
           
    </body>
        
    </html>
```

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Outra relacionada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/309370/como-declarar-e-usar-a-regra-viewport